# Adaptar archivo .PHP a .HTML para poder incrustar Javascript

Tags: php, javascript, html

```html
<?php
// Establecer conexión

session_start();
require_once "conexion_root.php";
?>
<?
// Ejecución de consulta SQL con INNER JOIN
 
$sql = "SELECT * FROM equipos"; 

if($result = $db_conn-><?query($sql)){
if($result-><?num_rows ><? 0){
?>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Inventario de Equipos</title>
<link href="./roundedcorners2.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link href="./result.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
</head>
 <body>    
  <p align="center"><a href="inventario.html"><img src="img\att_logo.png" width="150px"/></a></p>
  <p><h1 align="center" style="font-family: calibri">Inventario de Equipos</h1></p><br>
  
  <p><input id="buscar" type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Escriba algo para filtrar" /></p>

   <table id="tabla" class="roundedCorners2">    
    <thead>   
    <tr>
     <th>Tipo de Equipo:</th>
     <th>Número de Serie:</th>     
     <th>Marca:</th>
     <th>Modelo:</th>     
     <th>Unidades:</th>     
     <th>Proyecto:</th>     
     <th>Coordenadas del Rack:</th>     
     <th>Unidad_Inicial:</th>     
     <th>Unidad_Final:</th>     
     <th>Estado:</th>     
     <th>Situación:</th>     
     <th>Stack/Cluster:</th>     
     <th>Hostname:</th>     
     <th>IP Admin:</th>     
     <th>IOS:</th>     
     <th>Activo Fijo:</th>         
     <th>Notas: </th>     
       </tr>

  
       <? while($row = $result-><?fetch_array())<?{?>

    <tbody>   
    <tr>
     <td><? . $row['tipo_equipo'] . ?></td>
     <td><? . $row['no_serie'] . ?></td>     
     <td><? . $row['marca'] . ?></td>
     <td><? . $row['modelo'] . ?></td>   
     <td><? . $row['unidades'] . ?></td>     
     <td><? . $row['proyecto'] . ?></td>
     <td><? . $row['coordenadas_rack'] . ?></td>
     <td><? . $row['unidad_inicial'] . ?></td>
     <td><? . $row['unidad_final'] . ?></td>    
     <td><? . $row['estado'] . ?></td>
     <td><? . $row['situacion'] . ?></td>   
     <td><? . $row['stack_cluster'] . ?></td>
     <td><? . $row['hostname'] . ?></td>
     <td><? . $row['ip_admin'] . ?></td>     
     <td><? . $row['ios'] . ?></td>    
     <td><? . $row['activo_fijo'] . ?></td>      
     <td><? . $row['notas'] . ?></td>        
    </tr>  
    </tbody>    
   <? } ?>

   </table><br> 
      
 <div> 
  <table id="resultados" class="result">
   <tr>
    <td> 
    <?
     // Determinar el número de filas del resultado 
     $row_cnt = $result-><?num_rows; 
     
     <?printf("%d resultado(s) encontrado(s).\n", ?><?$row_cnt); 
    </td>    
   </tr>
  </table>
 </div> 
 </body>
</html>
<?
// Consulta libre de resultados
$result->free();
} else{
 echo 'No se encontró ningún resultado para esta consulta.<br><br>';
 echo '<a href="http://localhost/proyecto/insert_equipos.html">Dar de alta un equipo<br><br></a>';
}

} else{
    echo 'ERROR: No fue posible ejecutar la orden $sql. [' . $db_conn->errno . "] "
            . $db_conn->error;
}

// Cerrar conexión
$db_conn->close();
?>
```

Estimados, estos intentando adaptar el siguiente código PHP en HTML para poder insertar un scrip de Javascript. Ojalá alguién de ustedes me pueda ayudar un poco.

```
<html>
<?php    
// Establecer conexión

session_start();
require_once "conexion_root.php";

// Ejecución de consulta SQL

$sql = "SELECT * FROM equipos"; 

if($result = $db_conn->query($sql)){ 

    if($result->num_rows > 0){

        echo '<link href="./roundedcorners2.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />';      
        echo '<link href="./result.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />';

        echo '<p align="center"><a href="inventario.html"><img src="img\att_logo.png" width="150px"/></a></p>';
        echo '<p><h1 align="center" style="font-family: calibri">Inventario de Equipos</h1></p><br>';

        echo '<p><input id="buscar" type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Escriba algo para filtrar" /></p>';

            echo '<table id="tabla" class="roundedCorners2">';              
                echo '<thead>';         
                echo '<tr>';
                    echo '<th>Tipo de Equipo:</th>';
                    echo '<th>Número de Serie:</th>';                   
                    echo '<th>Marca:</th>';
                    echo '<th>Modelo:</th>';                    
                    echo '<th>Unidades:</th>';                  
                    echo '<th>Proyecto:</th>';                  
                    echo '<th>Coordenadas del Rack:</th>';                  
                    echo '<th>Unidad_Inicial:</th>';                    
                    echo '<th>Unidad_Final:</th>';                  
                    echo '<th>Estado:</th>';                    
                    echo '<th>Situación:</th>';                 
                    echo '<th>Stack/Cluster:</th>';                 
                    echo '<th>Hostname:</th>';                  
                    echo '<th>IP Admin:</th>';                  
                    echo '<th>IOS:</th>';                   
                    echo '<th>Activo Fijo:</th>';                                   
                    echo '<th>Notas: </th>';                    
                echo '</tr>';

        while($row = $result->fetch_array()){

                echo '<tbody>';         
                echo '<tr>';
                    echo '<td>' . $row['tipo_equipo'] . '</td>';
                    echo '<td>' . $row['no_serie'] . '</td>';                   
                    echo '<td>' . $row['marca'] . '</td>';
                    echo '<td>' . $row['modelo'] . '</td>';             
                    echo '<td>' . $row['unidades'] . '</td>';                   
                    echo '<td>' . $row['proyecto'] . '</td>';
                    echo '<td>' . $row['coordenadas_rack'] . '</td>';
                    echo '<td>' . $row['unidad_inicial'] . '</td>';
                    echo '<td>' . $row['unidad_final'] . '</td>';                   
                    echo '<td>' . $row['estado'] . '</td>';
                    echo '<td>' . $row['situacion'] . '</td>';                  
                    echo '<td>' . $row['stack_cluster'] . '</td>';
                    echo '<td>' . $row['hostname'] . '</td>';
                    echo '<td>' . $row['ip_admin'] . '</td>';                   
                    echo '<td>' . $row['ios'] . '</td>';                    
                    echo '<td>' . $row['activo_fijo'] . '</td>';                            
                    echo '<td>' . $row['notas'] . '</td>';                                      
                echo '</tr>';           
                echo'</tbody>';             
            }

            echo '</table><br>';    

    echo '<div>';   
        echo '<table id="resultados" class="result">';  
            echo '<tr>';    
                echo '<td>';    

                    // Determinar el número de filas del resultado 
                    $row_cnt = $result->num_rows;   

                    printf("%d resultado(s) encontrado(s).\n", $row_cnt);  

                echo '</td>';               
            echo '</tr>';   
        echo '</table>';    
    echo '</div>';

// Consulta libre de resultados
$result->free();
} else{
    echo 'No se encontró ningún resultado para esta consulta.<br><br>';
    echo '<a href="http://localhost/proyecto/insert_equipos.html">Dar de alta un equipo<br><br></a>';
}

} else{
    echo 'ERROR: No fue posible ejecutar la orden $sql. [' . $db_conn->errno . "] "
            . $db_conn->error;
}

// Cerrar conexión
$db_conn->close();
?>
</html>
```

Comment: Debes [edit] tu pregunta y agregar el código que acabas de agregar como respuesta, por favor lee [ask] y realiza el [tour] para que sepas cual es el funcionamiento básico del sitio, saludos!

Comment: Cómo puedo incrustar el código con formato PHP en esta página amigo?

Comment: Dale click al enlace [edit] y pegalo, nosotros lo arreglamos si se ve mal.

Comment: Buenas bienvenido a **StackOverflow** en español por favor antes de preguntar primero ve [¿Cómo elaboro una buena pregunta?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) y revisa también [Cómo crear un ejemplo mínimo, completo y verificable.](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) edita tu pregunta y mejorarla para tener una respuesta que realmente te ayude.

Comment: Muchisimas gracias @CamiloVasquez por tu ayuda editando mi código.

Comment: Ahora vamos con la solución a tu pregunta, esa es toda la estructura de tu sitio? por que no tienes etiquetas head body etc? por que todos los nodos los imprimes con echo? en pocas palabras tienes una estructura totalmente errónea

Comment: Estimado @Camilo Vasquez, lo que pasa es que tengo poca experiencia en el tema. A continuación compartiré el mismo código pero esta vez en mi intento por corregirlo y eliminar los echo. Sin embargo no me funciona.

Comment: @AntonioOrtiz entonces agrega el código sin los echo a la pregunta, y dime que no te funciona?

Comment: @CamiloVasquez listo, no me funciona el código ya que el array no me muestra la información que tengo en la tabla.

Comment: @CamiloVasquez, el archivo .php como tal si me muestra la tabla con información, sin embargo necesito añadir algo que me permita filtrar la información de la tabla. Por esto quiero convertir mi código .php a .html y así poder insertar javascript con el código para el filtrado.

Answer (score 1):

Tu pregunta es algo confusa y no deja claro qué es lo que deseas, aún así me aventuro a responder dos cosas:

1. Intenta programar siempre en capas, una capa HTML y CSS (con por ejemplo, bootstrap), otra con el javascript (jQuery o lo que desees) y otra con PHP que enlaza con los datos. De esta forma es muy sencillo cambiar toda la parte PHP sin tener que cambiar la web por ejemplo. Esto sería así (en un ejemplo muy sencillo):

Primero definimos la estructura de la página index.html:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <title>Hello, world!</title>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
        <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
        <link href="micss.css" rel="stylesheet">
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="contenedor"></div>
        <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js" integrity="sha256-hwg4gsxgFZhOsEEamdOYGBf13FyQuiTwlAQgxVSNgt4=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.3/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-vFJXuSJphROIrBnz7yo7oB41mKfc8JzQZiCq4NCceLEaO4IHwicKwpJf9c9IpFgh" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        <script src="micodigo.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Ahora aplicamos un diseño a micss.css:

```
* {
    margin: 0px;
}
```

Y ahora cargamos los datos desde micodigo.js por medio de llamadas AJAX al php:

```
$(function() {
    $.ajax({
        method: "POST",
        url: "datos.php",
        dataType: "json",
        cache: false,
        data: {
            action: 1
        }
    }).done(function(json) {
        switch(json.statuscode) {
            case 1:
                $(".contenedor").append(json.datos);
                break;
        }
    });
});
```

Por último, sacamos los datos a mostrar en el contendor desde datos.php:

```
<?php
    $return = array();
    $return["statuscode"] = 0; // Por defecto no hay error

    if(isset($_POST["action"])) {
        $action = sprintf("%d", $_POST["action"]);
    }

    switch($action) {
        case 1:
            $return["datos"] = "Hola mundo";
            break;
    }

    header('Content-type: application/json; charset=utf-8');
    echo json_encode($return);
    exit();
?>
```

Es un ejemplo muy sencillo, pero te ayuda a tener las cosas separadas para luego poder modificarlas facilmente.

2. Puedes simplemente ejecutar el código y guardar la página resultante desde el navegador, con esto tienes el HTML generado y limpio al que poder añadir el javascriprt.

Por último decirte que no hay ningún problema en añadir directamente el código javascript en el propio PHP. Por ejemplo:

```
echo '<td onclick="javascript: mifuncion();">' . $row['tipo_equipo'] . '</td>';
```

O puedes añadir otras cosas:

```
echo "<script>";
echo "alert('hola mundo');";
echo "</script>";
```

Y el resultado es que en el lado del cliente, verás el alert javascript generado desde PHP sin problemas.