# Adaptar un archivo .PHP a .HTML para insertar Javascript y filtrar tablas

Tags: php, javascript, html, sql, filtro

```js
 var busqueda = document.getElementById('buscar');
    var table = document.getElementById("tabla").tBodies[0];

    buscaTabla = function() {
      texto = busqueda.value.toLowerCase();
      var r = 0;
      while (row = table.rows[r++]) {
        if (row.innerText.toLowerCase().indexOf(texto) !== -1)
          row.style.display = null;
        else
          row.style.display = 'none';
      }
    }

    busqueda.addEventListener('keyup', buscaTabla);
```

```html
<?php
// Establecer conexión

session_start();
require_once "conexion_root.php";
?>
<?
// Ejecución de consulta SQL
 
$sql = "SELECT * FROM equipos"; 

if($result = $db_conn-><?query($sql)){
if($result-><?num_rows ><? 0){
?>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Inventario de Equipos</title>
<link href="./roundedcorners2.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link href="./result.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
</head>
 <body>    
  <p align="center"><a href="inventario.html"><img src="img\att_logo.png" width="150px"/></a></p>
  <p><h1 align="center" style="font-family: calibri">Inventario de Equipos</h1></p><br>
  
  <p><input id="buscar" type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Escriba algo para filtrar" /></p>

   <table id="tabla" class="roundedCorners2">    
    <thead>   
    <tr>
     <th>Tipo de Equipo:</th>
     <th>Número de Serie:</th>     
     <th>Marca:</th>
     <th>Modelo:</th>     
     <th>Unidades:</th>     
     <th>Proyecto:</th>     
     <th>Coordenadas del Rack:</th>     
     <th>Unidad_Inicial:</th>     
     <th>Unidad_Final:</th>     
     <th>Estado:</th>     
     <th>Situación:</th>     
     <th>Stack/Cluster:</th>     
     <th>Hostname:</th>     
     <th>IP Admin:</th>     
     <th>IOS:</th>     
     <th>Activo Fijo:</th>         
     <th>Notas: </th>     
       </tr>

  
       <? while($row = $result-><?fetch_array())<?{?>

    <tbody>   
    <tr>
     <td><? . $row['tipo_equipo'] . ?></td>
     <td><? . $row['no_serie'] . ?></td>     
     <td><? . $row['marca'] . ?></td>
     <td><? . $row['modelo'] . ?></td>   
     <td><? . $row['unidades'] . ?></td>     
     <td><? . $row['proyecto'] . ?></td>
     <td><? . $row['coordenadas_rack'] . ?></td>
     <td><? . $row['unidad_inicial'] . ?></td>
     <td><? . $row['unidad_final'] . ?></td>    
     <td><? . $row['estado'] . ?></td>
     <td><? . $row['situacion'] . ?></td>   
     <td><? . $row['stack_cluster'] . ?></td>
     <td><? . $row['hostname'] . ?></td>
     <td><? . $row['ip_admin'] . ?></td>     
     <td><? . $row['ios'] . ?></td>    
     <td><? . $row['activo_fijo'] . ?></td>      
     <td><? . $row['notas'] . ?></td>        
    </tr>  
    </tbody>    
   <? } ?>

   </table><br> 
      
 <div> 
  <table id="resultados" class="result">
   <tr>
    <td> 
    <?
     // Determinar el número de filas del resultado 
     $row_cnt = $result-><?num_rows; 
     
     <?printf("%d resultado(s) encontrado(s).\n", ?><?$row_cnt); 
    </td>    
   </tr>
  </table>
 </div> 
 </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Posible duplicado de [Adaptar archivo .PHP a .HTML para poder incrustar Javascript](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/126476/adaptar-archivo-php-a-html-para-poder-incrustar-javascript)

Comment: quieres un ejemplo de como enviar informacion a la base de datos con javascript  y php?  no se entiende lo que pides ¿insertar javascript ?

Comment: No está muy claro lo que realmente quieres hacer.

Comment: Es muy simple, el código en PHP que subí con "echo" por donde quiera, muestra una tabla que trae información de una tabla de base de datos por medio de una consulta sql, todo esto lo hice en PHP porque en HTML como tal no se puede consultar la base de datos. Ahora explico el tema del código javascript que quiero incrustar. A la tabla que se tiene de resultado del código PHP le quiero habilitar un filtro que permita buscar texto dentro de la tabla y ocultar lo que no coincida, sin embargo he visto que para hacer esto, debo adaptar mi código PHP a HTML.

Comment: ¿lo qué? 
Añade la explicación de lo que quieres hacer a tu pregunta, editala por favor.

Comment: Igual es mas fácil, que uses algún plugin, que te hace lo que quieres. Yo normalmente uso https://datatables.net/

Comment: Muchas gracias @JoseJavierSegura. Me gustaría saber si me puedes ayudar explicandome cómo podría integrar esos plugins en mi código.

Comment: Ya logré hacerlo funcionar. Gracias a todos los que intentaron ayudarme. También a los que no.